# Importing csv file to a table in the database also inserts the column names as values

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert these data to my table in the MySQL database using CSV import.

```
|id |employee_number    |name   |role|
     123456              Paul    Admin
```

But when I import it, I get two rows on my table like this

```
 |id    |employee_number    |name   |role|
  1       0                  name    role
  2       123456             Paul    Admin
```

My CSV file is structured simply like this,

```
|id |employee_number    |name   |role|
     123456              Paul    Admin
```

I import the CSV using phpMyAdmin with default import options, I'm not changing anything in the import options. Can anyone help please why am I getting an additional row of data?

Comment: You didn't exclude first row option in the import wizard.

Comment: @P.Salmon. Yeah, I guess that's it. Just quite confusing for me, the terms used in phpMyadmin. Here in this part "Skip this number of queries (for SQL) starting from the first one" the value there I just changed it from 0 to 1 and now it didn't include the first row which are the column names. I thought at first this first row in the csv is always going to be the column names and will be ignored automatically. Thanks

Comment: Not all csv files contain headers hence the option..Personally I prefer to use LOAD DATA INFILE than wizard. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html